Is there a switch to recover gcc-8.3 behavior?
gcc now pukes a lot of error messages about multiple definitions. There is an existing question:
"Multiple definition of" "first defined here" on GCC 10.2.1 but not GCC 8.3.0
that tells us to rummage through our codes, sometimes hundreds of thousands of lines, to fix a previously non-existent problem. A similar issue happened in gfortran, but there is a switch
-std=legacy that recovers the previous behavior. Is there a similar switch in gcc?

The first answer on the question you referred to already tells you exactly which flag to turn on to do this.

So does the second answer, which is just one sentence long.
